PHPMailer some emails blank
I have used PHPMailer for several years now with no issues but I'm now seeing issues on a few emails going out completely blank.
My code looks like this:
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'x';
$mail->Port =1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'y';
$mail->Password = 'x';
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->SMTPOptions = [
  'ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
  ]
];
$mail->setFrom('me-notifications@gmail.com', 'Me Notifications');
$mail->addAddress('me-notifications@gmail.com', 'Me Notifications');
$addresses = explode(',', $customerlist);
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $mail->addBCC($address);
}
$mail->Subject = "REMINDER: Test";
ob_start(); ?>
<html>
**Loads of HTML there with PHP Echo's**
</html>
<?php $body = ob_get_clean();
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Mail did not send';
} else {
echo 'Mail Sent - Sending 2nd email internally';
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->setFrom('me-notifications@gmail.com', 'Me Notifications');
$mail->addAddress('me-notifications@gmail.com', 'Me Notifications');
$mail->addBCC('internal@me.com', 'Internal Comms');
$mail->send();
}
?>

Overall, the code works fine.
I have obviously hidden some creds, host info, emails, etc but no concerns there.
You can see that I send one email to everyone in an Addresses variable as a BCC.
I then follow it up and send a second email to just a single email address.
The issue is with the first email being blank, not the second one.
Whether it is the cause or not in a recent example, the number of email addresses in the BCC field was over 5000 which is recent for us so could be caused somehow?
But I can't work out why the email would still send fine, no errors in the logs (I used SMTPDebug = 2) to show there is an issue, yet the content of the email, is blank.
This is some of the logs showing the content blank:
04-12-2024 13:16:50.665160      CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<test2@gmail.com>
04-12-2024 13:16:50.666264      SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok
04-12-2024 13:16:50.666309      CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<test1@me.com>
04-12-2024 13:16:50.667385      SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok
04-12-2024 13:16:50.667431      CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668255      SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668356      CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 4 Dec 2024 13:16:44 +0000
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668529      CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Me Notifications <me-notifications@me.com>
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668581      CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Me Notifications <me-notifications@me.com>
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668625      CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: REMINDER: Change Ref: 1 - Test Comms
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668668      CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <TQOLVqrBnPUPmoUYrKw52he6fozHTYqMITJqtzYwZ0@x.localnet>
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668710      CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.2.0 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668752      CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668795      CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668838      CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668881      CLIENT -> SERVER:
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668923      CLIENT -> SERVER:
04-12-2024 13:16:50.668971      CLIENT -> SERVER: .
04-12-2024 13:16:50.717486      SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A4A8C83E7A
04-12-2024 13:16:50.717819      CLIENT -> SERVER: RSET
04-12-2024 13:16:50.718576      SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok

Can see from 04-12-2024 13:16:50.668881 that it's blank, this is where it should show the email content.
The only PHP error I get is:
PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $descpull 

I don't believe this would be causing it though, although I can see why that error exists
Within the content:
$description_pull=($row['description']);
$htmlspecial = htmlspecialchars($descpull);
$description = nl2br($htmlspecial);
$description = nl2br($description_pull);

So don't know why the middle 2 lines are there to be honest, I'll delete
But I don't think an undefined variable, would cause this behaviour would it?
Wherever the variable is used, it would just be blank
Can anyone see a reason why this would be happening at all?
Could there be some limit above 5000 that somehow still allows it to send but just wipes the content?
Edit:
After digging further and some more examples even after splitting it to batches, I found it was erroring stating an email address was invalid:
09-12-2024 13:31:14.283035      Invalid address:  (to): steven@test.net​as

This shouldn't cause it to send a blank email so I checked the clear text version of the email and found it somehow contained "U+200B" unicode character between "net" and "as"
I will look to add validation and trim emails to avoid this, but, is it a bug that this then causes PHPMailer to send blank comms?
Any help would be appreciated

My first inclination would be to check the PHP error logs (with full error reporting and logging enabled) to see if there's a message in there. The "blank" might be similar to "white screen" which can happen if there's an error in the web SAPI.

The second might be to set debug to DEBUG_LOWLEVEL to see if there's anything of interest at that detail level.

Added some PHP error content to the main question
Also, I'm hesitant to go and test again without making changes, given I'm sending 5000 blank emails to our customer base :)
Anything else we think we can look at?

Don't you have a test environment where you can reproduce the issue, and send emails to a default address?

$htmlspecial = htmlspecialchars($descpull); $description = nl2br($htmlspecial); seems to be entirely pointless since you overwrite $description on the next line anyway. Looks like something someone changed to ignore this bit of code, but then forgot to actually remove it

100% Agree, I've removed it anyway, just stating in here for full clarity as to how the code looked when the issue occurs and what the PHP errors say
Test bed wise, Yes, but I don't have 5000+ dummy emails I can use

Doesn't matter...send them all to a single sink / override address. But just put that address in BCC 5000+ times. If the content, or quantity of emails is the issue, as you suspect, then the destination shouldn't matter.

For further debugging I would re-order to code and add some of your own logging. I'd have the first step of your code create the HTML and log information about that. If for whatever reason you get what appears to be "blank", there's no reason to proceed with anything related to email. Once you know you have content, then move on to PHPMailer.

I would be very suspicious of what's in $body; you have no error checking around setting that, so if your output buffer is empty, your message will have no body. Also, disabling certificate checks is always a bad sign; fix it properly!

I would agree, but that same $body is used on the 2nd email, which is never blank
Also, I tried adding a line count if statement:
$line_count = count(explode("\n", $body));
if ($line_count > 50){
Within the statement if it was over 50, do both of the sends, if not, give me an error
Even this did not capture it and stop the email sending
This leads me to think that the content is getting wiped after my code?

1 email with 5000 addresses is not very tenable, I'm amazed you've gotten that far. Rather, you should be sending 5000 emails each with one address, preferably via a service like SES or Mailgun. This gives you much more reasonable debugging, and the ability to distribute load, personalize content, and track receives and bounces.

I don't really have the scope to change solution, I need to work with this one unfortunately so if we are saying the 5000 emails is causing the issue vs 4800 working for example, then I will look to split the emails

Not sure what scope you're referring to -- it would be simpler to change this code to send one message per recipient than to split the BCCs into multiple chunks. That said, determining if 5000 is indeed the problem is an easy test, just remove the addBCC() calls and see if you get content.

There's a thread in PHPMailer about a large number of recipients and header-folding. No idea if this is your problem, but I'm just nothing it.

We looked into this further and confirmed two things.
The PHP code was definitely passing on the email body content correctly to the PHPMailer elements.
The Mail Relay server was not receiving the content.
Few things spotted:

More examples of blank emails where BCC count was greater than 5k
Noticed the $customerlist on the examples given had spaces, tabs, new lines, unclear if it caused issues but changed how this variable is set to remove those
I need to do a re-write on the code overall, I won't pain you showing you it but I haven't properly handled special characters and I'm not confident quotation marks within $description which was an element of the HTML code could be causing it, so I removed these

I have just re-sent the comms with:

Splitting the comms into bunches of 1000 BCC
Removing any spaces, new lines and tabs from the $customerlist
Removed special characters from $description as a precaution

This worked fine
For anyone else's benefit, here is the piece of code used to split it out:
$addresses = explode(',', $customerlist);
$chunks = array_chunk($addresses,1000);
    
foreach ($chunks as $index => $chunk) {
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->addAddress('noreply@test.com', 'Notifications');
 
    foreach ($chunk as $address) {
        $mail->addBCC($address);
    }

    **Original code here containing the ob_start and HTML content**
    
    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo "Mail Sent";
    } else {
        echo "Mail NOT Sent";
    }
}

So haven't worked out why over 5000 is causing issues, or whether its another element, but at least works

I've had another example of the issue, when checking which batch it was, it had one error
"09-12-2024 11:04:11.492023      Invalid address:  (bcc): incorrect.mail@test.net?as"
As no difference between others, I presume this has somehow caused the issues?
Is there a reason why PHPMailer would send blank comms rather than just ignoring the invalid address?
